# Changing the height of ng-table

Tags: angularjs, html, web, ngtable

I am dynamically creating tables using ng-table, based on the json data. Ng-tables automatically adjust their height based on the amount of rows.

Is there a way that I can fix the size of the tables, so all of them are of the same size, based on the table with the maximum rows (maximum height)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by wrapping your `table` tag inside a div and then give height to that wrapper div. Give `height` and `width` to wrapper div and also give `overflow-y:scroll`

**CSS**

```
#scrollable-area {
  margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: 150px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    overflow-y: scroll; /* <-- here is what is important*/
}
```

**HTML**

```
   <div id="scrollable-area">
          <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
          </table>
    </div>
```

[**Plunkr here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/F79kvbAdrXFxJZLO0AqP?p=preview)